2^N different words with N characters matching a regex of the form [ab][cd]
Results here will be actually be useful for me, I am looking to use them in teaching statistics/information theory.
The words "as, at, is, it" match [ai][st]. The words "bad, bat, bed, bet, mad, mat, med, met" match [bm][ae][dt] (thank you Claude Sonnet! Who couldn't do N=4).
I am looking for a longer regex of the same form. Even 4 will make me happy. That is: I want series of N two-letter choices that matches 2^N english words. You are allowed to repeat letters across brackets (but not within brackets e.g. [aa] is not allowed but [ab][ac] is). I am looking for ideally N=4.
Standard/recognizable-to-me words preferred!
Edit: Alright, with slight feeling of worry, let's define "recognizable english word" as "word on wiktionary's list of the most common 100,000 words which does not start with a capital letter" https://gist.github.com/h3xx/1976236

This seems more appropriate for puzzling.se than this site. We tend to be pretty rigid about objective requirements, so I imagine you will be asked to define precisely what an English word is.

Reasonable! Edited.

Please be aware that the referenced list includes some exact duplicates.

It'd be interesting to investigate this in other languages as well.

N=4
Regex
/^[ct][ao][np][es]$/

Words
cane, cans, cape, caps,
cone, cons, cope, cops,
tane, tans, tape, taps,
tone, tons, tope, tops

Search code (Node.js)
This is the one and only solution found by this code.
const fs = require("fs");
const data = fs.readFileSync("words.txt").toString().split("\n");

const SHOW_ALL = false;

function search(N) {
  const re = RegExp(`^[a-z]{${N}}$`),
        dict = [ ...new Set(data.filter(w => re.test(w))) ];

  let best = SHOW_ALL ? 1 : 2 ** N;

  recursiveSearch(dict);

  function recursiveSearch(list, pos = 0, path = "") {
    if(pos == N) {
      if(list.length >= best) {
        best = list.length;
        console.log(best);
        console.log(`/^${path}$/`);
        console.log(list.sort().join(", ") + "\n");
      }
      return;
    }

    let chars = [ ...new Set(list.map(w => w[pos])) ];

    chars.forEach(x => {
      chars.forEach(y => {
        if(y > x) {
          let newList = list.filter(w => w[pos] == x || w[pos] == y);

          if(newList.length >= best) {
            recursiveSearch(newList, pos + 1, path + `[${x + y}]`);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

search(4);

Try it online! (dictionary limited to 4-character words for TIO)

N=5 (no solution)
Out of curiosity, I've tried to search \$N=5\$ (and beyond).
The best score is 19 words, which is -- unsurprisingly -- pretty far from 32.
/^[ch][ao][lr][dt][es]$/
cards, carte, carts, colde, colds, colts, corde, cords, corte, halte, halts, harde, harte, harts, holde, holds, holte, horde, horte

/^[cp][ao][rs][et][es]$/
cares, carte, carts, cases, caste, casts, cores, corte, costs, parte, parts, paste, pores, porte, ports, posee, poses, poste, posts

/^[cp][ao][rs][st][ae]$/
carta, carte, casse, caste, corse, corta, corte, costa, parse, parte, passa, passe, paste, porta, porte, possa, posse, posta, poste


my code turns up [dl][io][nr][ae], [mp][ae][rt][es], and [ps][ei][nt][st] for 4 as well

Disregard the previous comment, I figured out why. I missed the "does not start with a capital letter" criteria for words. Indeed there is only one solution.

Python 3
A full program that accepts an integer and a file path (without a path uses stdin, only implemented for the TIO suite really) and prints sets of words that equal or beat the maximal cardinality found so far.
The find function could be passed a floor of 2 ** word_length to not search for smaller than full sets (or could do that by default), this is just so we can see the best when no sets are "full" ones.
Here are the record breakers it finds for \$N \in [4,10]\$ (there are \$7965\$ length eight sets for \$N=3\$):



N
Length
Word Set




4
16
cane cans cape caps cone cons cope cops tane tans tape taps tone tons tope tops


5
19
cards carte carts colde colds colts corde cords corte halte halts harde harte harts holde holds holte horde horte


5
19
cares carte carts cases caste casts cores corte costs parte parts paste pores porte ports posee poses poste posts


5
19
carta carte casse caste corse corta corte costa parse parte passa passe paste porta porte possa posse posta poste


6
17
cantar canter cartas carter cartes contar conter contes corner cornes cortes manner mannes monter montes mortar mortes


6
17
cantar canter cartas carter cartes conies contar conter contes cortes manier marier monies monter montes mortar mortes


7
16
changed changer chanted chanter chatted chatter clanged clangor clatter clotted planted planter platter plonger plotted plotter


7
16
partait partant parting parvint portait portant pouting pouvait pouvant sautait sautant sortait sortant sorting soutint souvint


7
16
pendait pendant pendent perdait perdant perdent portait portant portent sentais sentait sentant sentent sortait sortant sortent


7
16
pendait pendant pendent perdait perdant perdent portait portant portend portent sentait sentant sentent sortait sortant sortent


7
16
pendait pendant pendent perdait perdant perdent pertain portait portant portent sentait sentant sentent sortait sortant sortent


8
14
clacking clanging clanking clicking clinging clinking crackers cracking cringing flanking flickers flicking flinging fringing


8
14
clacking clanging clanking clicking clinging clinking cracking crackled cringing crinkled flanking flicking flinging fringing


8
14
blacking blankets blinking brackets bringing clacking clanging clanking clicking clinging clinking cracking crickets cringing


8
14
deserved deserves devolved devolves diversas diverses reserved reserves resolved resolves reversed reverses revolved revolves


8
14
deserved deserves devolved devolves diverses diversos reserved reserves resolved resolves reversed reverses revolved revolves


9
12
contorted contenter consentir presenter consorted preserver consented contented conserver conserved presented preserved


10
11
consenting consistait consisting contentait contenting contesting continuait continuant continuing protestant protesting


10
11
consenting consistait consisting contentait contenting contesting continuait continuant continuing presentait presenting



...if repeats were allowed there is a \$17\$ for \$N=7\$ ([cb][lr][au][is][hs][ee][ds]: clashes classed cruised crushes blushed bruises cruises brushed brasses crushed blushes clashed bruised classes crashed brushes crashes)
import sys

LETTERS = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'


def find(word_length, words, floor=1, i=0):
    if i >= word_length:
        if all(len(set(column)) == 2 for column in zip(*tuple(words))):
            yield words
    else:
        allowed_letters = tuple(set(w[i] for w in words))
        for n, left in enumerate(allowed_letters, 1):
            for right in allowed_letters[n:]:
                filtered_words = {w for w in words if w[i] == left or w[i] == right}
                if len(filtered_words) < floor:
                    continue
                for result in find(word_length, filtered_words, floor, i + 1):
                    floor = len(result)
                    yield result


def main():
    word_length = int(sys.argv[1])
    if sys.argv[2:]:
        words_filepath = sys.argv[2]
        word_file = open(words_filepath, mode='r', encoding="utf8")
    else:
        word_file = sys.stdin
    words = set()
    for line in word_file.readlines():
        if line.startswith("#"):
            continue
        word = line.strip('\n')
        if len(word) == word_length and all(c in LETTERS for c in word):
            words.add(word)
    for found in find(word_length, words):
        print(len(found), found)
    print("Done.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Try it online! - you may want to collapse the "Input" section. This is for \$N=3\$ as TIO is too slow to do much more.

How may repeat help? You can use [ex] to replace [ee] without lossing any possibility

@l4m2 Yep, being a bit slow here :D ...I read the "but not within brackets eg..." as meaning the resulting word-set could not only use one letter in the identified position. Thinking about it, it's kind of redundant since a full-set will always need two distinct letters (otherwise it would contain repeated words). So when we relax to non-maximal word-sets we have a choice of what we are looking for in that regard I suppose.
